# Tallying number of times certain strings occur in Python

Tags: python, database, string, list, pandas

Im working on a database of incidents affecting different sectors in different countries and want to create a table tallying the incident rate breakdown for each country.

The database looks like this atm

```
Incident Name  |  Country Affected  |  Sector Affected
incident_1     |  US,TW,CN          |  Engineering,Media
incident_2     |  FR,RU,CN          |  Government
etc., etc.
```

My aim would be to build a which looks like this:

```
Country  |  Engineering  |  Media  |  Government
CN       |  3            |  0      |  5
etc.
```

Right now my method is basically to use an if loop to check if the country column contains a specific string (for example 'CN') and if this returns True then to run Counter from collections to create a dictionary of the initial tally, then save this.

My issue is how to scale this us to a level where it can be run across the entire database AND how to actually save the dictionary produced by Counter.

Comment: Would you mind editing your post to show what code you have so far?

Comment: Is there any possibility your database can be changed? (US, Engineering), (TW, Engineering), (CN, Engineering), etc.  should all be separate rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`pd.Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and `pd.DataFrame.dot`**

```
c = df['Country Affected'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
s = df['Sector Affected'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')

c.T.dot(s)

    Engineering  Government  Media
CN            1           1      1
FR            0           1      0
RU            0           1      0
TW            1           0      1
US            1           0      1
```

---

**bigger example**

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])

countries = ['CN', 'FR', 'RU', 'TW', 'US', 'UK', 'JP', 'AU', 'HK']
sectors = ['Engineering', 'Government', 'Media', 'Commodidty']

def pick_rnd(x):
    i = np.random.randint(1, len(x))
    j = np.random.choice(x, i, False)
    return ','.join(j)

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Country Affected': [pick_rnd(countries) for _ in range(10)],
        'Sector Affected': [pick_rnd(sectors) for _ in range(10)]
    })

df

          Country Affected               Sector Affected
0                       CN              Government,Media
1  FR,TW,JP,US,UK,CN,RU,AU         Commodidty,Government
2                 HK,AU,JP                    Commodidty
3           RU,CN,FR,JP,UK  Media,Commodidty,Engineering
4  CN,RU,FR,JP,TW,HK,US,UK   Government,Media,Commodidty
5                    FR,CN                    Commodidty
6     FR,HK,JP,TW,US,AU,CN                    Commodidty
7  CN,HK,RU,TW,UK,US,FR,JP              Media,Commodidty
8                 JP,UK,AU             Engineering,Media
9                 RU,UK,FR                         Media
```

Then

```
c = df['Country Affected'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
s = df['Sector Affected'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')

c.T.dot(s)

    Commodidty  Engineering  Government  Media
AU           3            1           1      1
CN           6            1           3      4
FR           6            1           2      4
HK           4            0           1      2
JP           6            2           2      4
RU           4            1           2      4
TW           4            0           2      2
UK           4            2           2      5
US           4            0           2      2
```

Comment: That's awesome, I can't thank you enough. I thought I was going to be going through tonnes of embedded loops and its just 2 lines....

Comment: @Lublamai glad I could help.